# Can't debug Azure Stream Analytics Cosmos DB output in VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to build an Azure Stream Analytics job in VS Code using the Azure Stream Analytics Tools extension. I have added an event hub as an input and a data lake gen 2 storage account as an output and I can successfully run the job in VS Code using "Use Live Input and Live Output".

The issue I'm having is when I try to set the output to an Azure Cosmos DB Document DB instead I get an error "Failed to convert output 'cosmosdb' : Unsupported data source type.." when trying to use live input and output. I can however use successfully run the job using "Live input and local output"

Is this a limitation of the VS Code extension that you can't debug live output against Cosmos DB? Or have I set something up incorrectly in my cosmos db output? See cosmos db output code

```
{
"Name": "cosmosdb",
"DataSourceType": "DocumentDB",
"DocumentDbProperties": {
    "AccountId": "cosmosdb-dev-eastau-001",
    "AccountKey": null,
    "Database": "cosmosdb_db",
    "ContainerName": "container1",
    "DocumentId": ""
},
"DataSourceCredentialDomain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.StreamAnalystics",
"ScriptType": "Output"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Live Input to Live Output mode, the only supported output adapters (for now) are Event Hub, Storage Account, and Azure SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/visual-studio-code-local-run-all#local-run-modes

Comment: Thanks! Thought I'd read all of the docs, but must have missed that but